# Inserting dynamic table values from PHP array to MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

Need help in inserting dynamic fields and values into mysql db table in PHP.
sampe data

```
$data[] = array( 'client'=>$clientname, 
                 'amount' => 12000,
                 'balance'=>6000, 
                 'term'=>6,
                 'maturitydate'=>'2016-05-31'
               )
```

parameters passed to get the above data : branch = branchid, date =cutoffdate

Here's the table structure where I need to insert the above data.

Fields : 
    branch,
    date,
    account_no,
    field,
    value

the first two fields values came from the parameters passed, account_no comes from the data after the querying the db using the passed param, for the field value should come from the array index and value is the index value. 
table after inserting data

```
branch   date         account_no field    value 
br001    2016-03-31   0010GL001  client   Client Name 1
br001    2016-03-31   0010GL001  amount   12000
br001    2016-03-31   0010GL001  balance  6000
```

......

Been looking around the web for some possible solutions but I cannot find one. 
Any help will be highly appreciated. thank you

Comment: show us your query

Comment: Its radicle, but you could always just code something rather than trying to use someone elses code.

Comment: Can you add some more values in array so get clear idea what data you have to add. Also Fields not clear. Please edit your question to format it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have first three values already (`branch`, `date`, `account_no`) and `$clientname` is also assigned, you can use `foreach()`, so the script should be like this:

```
<?php
    $branch = 'br001';
    $date   = '2016-03-31';
    $accNo  = '0010GL001';
    $clientname = 'client_name';
    $data = array('client' => $clientname,
        'amount' => 12000,
        'balance' => 6000,
        'term' => 6,
        'maturitydate' => '2016-05-31'
    );
    foreach ($data as $field => $value) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO db_table 
                (`branch`, `date`, `account_no`, `field`, `value`) 
            VALUES 
                ('" . $branch . "', '" . $date . "', '" . $accNo . "', '" . $field . "', '" . $value . "')";
        echo $query . '<br>';
        mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    }
?>
```

This will produce following queries:

```
INSERT INTO db_table (`branch`, `date`, `account_no`, `field`, `value`) VALUES ('br001', '2016-03-31', '0010GL001', 'client', 'client_name')
INSERT INTO db_table (`branch`, `date`, `account_no`, `field`, `value`) VALUES ('br001', '2016-03-31', '0010GL001', 'amount', '12000')
INSERT INTO db_table (`branch`, `date`, `account_no`, `field`, `value`) VALUES ('br001', '2016-03-31', '0010GL001', 'balance', '6000')
INSERT INTO db_table (`branch`, `date`, `account_no`, `field`, `value`) VALUES ('br001', '2016-03-31', '0010GL001', 'term', '6')
INSERT INTO db_table (`branch`, `date`, `account_no`, `field`, `value`) VALUES ('br001', '2016-03-31', '0010GL001', 'maturitydate', '2016-05-31')
```